# Spring batch extract xml record from database

Tags: xml, database, spring-batch, record

I have a database Table  with three columns: id, description and date, the id column is numeric, the description column is a string which contains an xml line and a date column.
the description column is something like this :

```
  <catalog_item >
         <item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
         <price>39.95</price>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Large">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
  </catalog_item>
  <catalog_item >
         <item_number>RRX9856</item_number>
         <price>42.50</price>
         <size description="Small">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
         </size>
         <size description="Medium">
            <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
            <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
         </size>

  </catalog_item>
```

with multiple nested tags.
All tags are written in the same record in the description column.
I can write a  select statement to read the record from the database , but in this case, i'll have a custom object which contains the whole row from the description column, is there a way to extract all these nodes of the xml line into separated java fields  with spring batch.

Thks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not really spring-batch's job to transform XML files into DTOs (or any java bean), you should use something like Jaxb (or any other XML mapping library).

As for spring-batch, you could call Jaxb in a [FieldSetMapper](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#fieldSetMapper) (a component between the `reader` and the `processor` that maps objects).

Comment: I'll try this solution.Thnks